# MySQL Query: Find column where key like "Y" then use another columns unique ID to update a third column with something?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am going to try to do my best to explain the SQL query I'm trying to achieve

I have the following structure:

**Table** usermeta

**Columns:** : user_id, meta_key, meta_value

I need to find all **meta_key** where '_expired_user_expired" and **meta_value** is 'Y'

```
SELECT * 
FROM usermeta
WHERE meta_key LIKE '_expire_user_expired' AND meta_value LIKE 'y';
```

Now to the hard part (for me)

I need to use the unique value from column **user_id** to update **meta_key** 'user_disabled' to have **meta_value** '1'.

Visual explanation:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║   user_id    ║    meta_key            ║     meta_value   ║
╠══════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════╣
║      1       ║ user_disabled          ║         0        ║
║      1       ║ _expired_user_expired  ║         Y        ║
║      2       ║ user_disabled          ║         0        ║
║      2       ║ _expired_user_expired  ║         N        ║
║      3       ║ user_disabled          ║         0        ║
║      3       ║ _expired_user_expired  ║         N        ║
╠══════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════╣
```

After a successful query would become:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║   user_id    ║    meta_key            ║     meta_value   ║
╠══════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════╣
║      1       ║ user_disabled          ║         1        ║
║      1       ║ _expired_user_expired  ║         Y        ║
║      2       ║ user_disabled          ║         0        ║
║      2       ║ _expired_user_expired  ║         N        ║
║      3       ║ user_disabled          ║         0        ║
║      3       ║ _expired_user_expired  ║         N        ║
╠══════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════╣
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the update join syntax:

```
UPDATE usermeta a
JOIN   usermeta b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND
                     a.meta_key = 'user_disabled' AND
                     b.meta_key = '_expired_user_expired' AND
                     b.meta_value = 'Y'
SET    a.meta_value = 1
```